# can I use goole calender API with VBA (to create a calender entry from MS-Excel)

Tags: vba, google-calendar-api

I like to create a new google calender entry from Microsoft Excel 2016, how can I do this?

I tried the following code, but I get a Timeout at "xmlhttp.send ...".

```
Sub AddGoogleKalenderEntry()
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    xmlhttp.Open "POST", "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin", False
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    xmlhttp.send "accountType=HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE&Email=<User>@gmail.com&Passwd=<PWD>" & "&source=Gulp-CalGulp-1.05&service=cl"

    Lines = Split(xmlhttp.responseText, vbLf)
    nvp = Split(Lines(2), "=")

    Set xmlhttp = Nothing

    calentry = "<?xml version='1.0' ?><entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' " _
    & "xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>" _
    & "<category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' " _
    & "term='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event'></category>" _
    & "<title type='text'>Tennis with Beth</title>" _
    & "<content type='text'>Meet for a quick lesson.</content>" _
    & "<gd:transparency " _
    & "value='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event.opaque'>" _
    & "</gd:transparency>" _
    & "<gd:eventStatus " _
    & "value='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event.confirmed'>" _
    & "</gd:eventStatus>" _
    & "<gd:where valueString='Rolling Lawn Courts'></gd:where>" _
    & "<gd:when startTime='2010-01-22T15:00:00.000Z' " _
    & "endTime='2010-01-22T17:00:00.000Z'></gd:when>" _
    & "</entry>"

    url = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full"

    Call postEntry(url, nvp)


End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: From Review: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58389190/edit) your own question and add the code properly formatted to your post. Avoid writing comments to your own post when not necessary. See: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: From Google's [ClientLogin API page](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/auth/clientlogin): "Important: Do not use ClientLogin for new applications. Instead, use the more secure OAuth authentication protocol. ClientLogin is a deprecated authentication protocol and is being **turned down on April 20, 2015."**